# How can I easily download/save an attachment in mu4e?

Tags: mu4e, attachment

The title says it all. When I press <kbd>A</kbd> with opened email, it
proposes the following options:

- open with
- open in emacs
- import in diary
- pipe (haven't tried that)

Is there something straightforward to just save an attachment on disk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `e`:

> e runs the command mu4e-view-save-attachment
>
> Offer to save attachment(s). If MULTI (prefix-argument) is nil, save a
>   single one, otherwise, offer to save a range of attachments.

Alternatively, with point on an attachment name, you can use `S-RET`:

> S-return runs the command mu4e~view-save-attach-from-binding
>
> Save the attachement at point, or click location.

Comment: For me `e` offers view attachment not save it (mu4e v1.10.3). Probably the actions changed since the date of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In view buffer point cursor to the line with attachment:

- press `o` for saving it
- press `e` for viewing externally

Also if you run GNU/Emacs in graphical mode, then right mouse on the attachment displays menu with possible actions for selected MIME part.